# jquery - back to top

Tags: jquery

I see this fiddle sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/robert/fjXSq/)

I want when "to the top" appear, an click! should scroll to the top smoothly or slow

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop()) {
        $('#toTop').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('#toTop').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

```
$("#toTop").click(function () {
   //1 second of animation time
   //html works for FFX but not Chrome
   //body works for Chrome but not FFX
   //This strange selector seems to work universally
   $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 1000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fjXSq/161/

Answer (score 21):

[Updated JSFiddle with solution](http://jsfiddle.net/mnQb6/)

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop()) {
        $('#toTop').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('#toTop').fadeOut();
    }
});

$("#toTop").click(function() {
    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 1000);
 });
```

Comment: Wow - this should be the marked answer. Short and to the point! I was waay over complicating this.

Comment: Worked like a champ for me as well.

Answer (score 12):

First lets create the button.

```
<a href="#" class="scrollToTop">Scroll To Top</a>
```

Now we can style the button with the following CSS.

```
<style>
.scrollToTop{
    width:100px; 
    height:130px;
    padding:10px; 
    text-align:center; 
    background: whiteSmoke;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #444;
    text-decoration: none;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:75px;
    right:40px;
    display:none;
    background: url('arrow_up.png') no-repeat 0px 20px;
}
.scrollToTop:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
}
</style>
```

Copy and paste the following in the Javascript file to add the Javascript functionality.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    //Check to see if the window is top if not then display button
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('.scrollToTop').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.scrollToTop').fadeOut();
        }
    });
    
    //Click event to scroll to top
    $('.scrollToTop').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
        return false;
    });
    
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

[See JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rms2014/orxp04pq/)

```
       $(window).on("scroll",function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50 ) {
            $('#toTop').fadeIn(400);
        } else {
            $('#toTop').fadeOut(400);
        }
    });

    $("#toTop").on("click",function() {
        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 1200);
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $(window).scroll(function(){ 
       if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) { 
           $('#toTop').fadeIn(); 
       } else { 
           $('#toTop').fadeOut(); 
       } 
   }); 
   $('#toTop').click(function(){ 
       $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600); 
       return false; 
   }); 
});
```

Live demo, full script and tutorial can be check from here -  [Back to top button using jQuery and CSS](http://www.codexworld.com/back-to-top-button-using-jquery-css/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jQuery js code variant :

```
$(function () {
    const $btt = $('.back-to-top');

    $btt.hide();

    $btt.on('click', function () {
      window.scrollTo({top: 0, behavior: 'smooth'});
    });

    let y,
        isVisible = false;
    
    $(document).on('scroll', function () {
      y = $(this).scrollTop();
      if (y > 500 && !isVisible) {
        $btt.fadeIn();
        isVisible = true;
      } else if (y <= 500 && isVisible) {
        $btt.fadeOut();
        isVisible = false;
      }
    });
  });
```

Add an `isVisible` variable to execute `fadeIn / fadeOut` only when necessary.